# Devise validations not working Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am using a custom controller to handle Devise actions.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def new
    @joining_group = params[:access_token]
    session[:access_token] = params[:access_token]
    super
  end

  def create
    super
    sign_in resource_name, resource # sign in the user so that the code below works

    if params[:organization] # User is an admin and creates group
      current_user.admin = true
      new_group = Group.create( name: params[:organization], access_token: SecureRandom.hex ) # add super secret token to group so other users can be invited to join
      current_user.group = new_group
      current_user.save!
    else # user is joining vis a vis email invitation with access_token
      current_user.group_id = Group.where( access_token: session[:access_token] ).first.id
      current_user.save!
    end
  end

  def update
    super
  end

  def group_params
    params.require(:group).permit(:name)
  end
end
```

However, when I try to create a new user I get the following error in my browser when I have an empty input tag (if all inputs are filled the create works just fine):

```
NoMethodError in RegistrationsController#create
undefined method `admin=' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #12):
10 super
11 if params[:organization] # User is an admin and creates group
12 current_user.admin = true
13 new_group = Group.create( name: params[:organization], access_token: SecureRandom.hex ) 
14 current_user.group = new_group
15 current_user.save!
```

The validatable module is turned on in my user class. My registration/new.html.erb view is as such:

```
<div class="logo">
  <h1>VitalTracker</h1>
</div>

<div class="registration_box">
  <% if @joining_group %>
    <h2>Join Group</h2>
  <% else %>
    <h2>Create Account</h2>
  <% end %>

  <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>

    <div>
      <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true, placeholder: "Email", class: "registration_input" %>
    </div>

    <div>
      <%= f.password_field :password, placeholder: "Password", class: "registration_input" %>
    </div>

    <div>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, placeholder: "Confirm Password", class: "registration_input" %>
    </div>

    <div>
      <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Name", class: "registration_input" %>
    </div>

    <% unless @joining_group %>
      <div>
        <%= text_field_tag "organization", nil,  placeholder: "Organization", class: "registration_input" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <div>
      <%= f.submit "Create Account", class: "registration_btn large_btn" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
</div>
```

Server log below:

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-22 16:05:56 -0500
Processing by RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"eBTmAyknoi92qdbhiirlUfjjtbdOiD8jzYwp6ZE9dwI=", "user"=>{"email"=>"", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "name"=>""}, "organization"=>"", "commit"=>"Create Account"}
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (3.8ms)
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "current_sign_in_at", "current_sign_in_ip", "last_sign_in_at", "last_sign_in_ip", "name", "sign_in_count", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Sat, 22 Feb 2014 21:05:56 UTC +00:00], ["current_sign_in_at", Sat, 22 Feb 2014 21:05:56 UTC +00:00], ["current_sign_in_ip", "127.0.0.1"], ["last_sign_in_at", Sat, 22 Feb 2014 21:05:56 UTC +00:00], ["last_sign_in_ip", "127.0.0.1"], ["name", ""], ["sign_in_count", 1], ["updated_at", Sat, 22 Feb 2014 21:05:56 UTC +00:00]]
   (0.6ms)  COMMIT
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "groups" ("access_token", "created_at", "name", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["access_token", "103ff607863b1f766d3cd1b23d1f57dd"], ["created_at", Sat, 22 Feb 2014 21:05:56 UTC +00:00], ["name", ""], ["updated_at", Sat, 22 Feb 2014 21:05:56 UTC +00:00]]
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 94ms

ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Email can't be blank):
  app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:17:in `create'


  Rendered /Users/jonathantrope/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@rails4/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered /Users/jonathantrope/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@rails4/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered /Users/jonathantrope/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@rails4/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered /Users/jonathantrope/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@rails4/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (19.2ms)
```

Thanks.

Comment: please share your Registrations new view and also server logs when you sign up a user.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `current_user`, add `before_filter :authenticate_user!` to your controller. Looking at the [source](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb) of `Devise::RegistrationsController` I think you want to use `resource` instead of `current_user`.

Btw creating an admin based on the `params[:organization]` is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

`current_user` is nil because no-one is signed in.

You need something like this:

```
def create
  super

  # sign in after registration
  sign_in resource_name, resource

  # then the rest of your code shuold be ok
  if params[:organization] # User is an admin and creates group
    current_user.admin = true
    # etc
```

Comment: The problem is that if I submit with blank fields (e.g. blank email), I get the following browser error: ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid in RegistrationsController#create - Validation failed: Email can't be blank. And it does create a user record in my database, with the fields blank.

Comment: In addition, when I again submit a new invalid user I get the following  browser error: PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_users_on_email" DETAIL: Key (email)=() already exists. : INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "current_sign_in_at", "current_sign_in_ip", "last_sign_in_at", "last_sign_in_ip", "name", "sign_in_count", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING "id"

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to calling current_user.save!, which prevented invalid create error messages to be shown by devise in the view as intended. Using current_user.save fixes it.